# Insert to 2 tables from custom route

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a Rails app where the user can select from a table of data (**cosmics**) from an index page. 
I have a button on that page, which is connected to a custom route **start_batch**. The route appears on rake:routes, although without an GET or PUT.

and when it is pressed I would like to create rows in two other tables: **batches** and **batch_details**.

Instead, when I press the button, Rails is trying to go to the show action for the **cosmics** controller.

**rake:routes**

```
start_batch        /cosmics/start_batch(.:format)                      cosmics#start_batch
```

**cosmics_controller**

```
def start_batch
  @batch = Batch.create!(:status => 'created',:status_timestamp => Time.now)
  @cosmics.where(:selected == true) do |cosmic|
    @batch_detail = BatchDetail.create!(:batch_id => @batch.id, :gene => @cosmic.gene,   :mut_freq => @cosmic.mut_freq)
    @batch_detail.save
  end
end
```

**routes.rb**

```
resources :batches do
  resources :batch_details
end

resources :cosmics 
match '/cosmics/start_batch', :to => 'cosmics#start_batch', :as => 'start_batch'
```

**cosmics/index.html.erb**

```
<%= link_to 'Process', start_batch_path, :class =>"btn btn-primary" %>
```

Do I have an error I can't see or am I doing this completely incorrectly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to put the `start_batch` route before the `resources :cosmics`

```
match '/cosmics/start_batch', :to => 'cosmics#start_batch', :as => 'start_batch'**
resources :cosmics
```

Rails uses the first route that match the requested url in the `routes.rb`. The line `resources :cosmics` generates a route `get /cosmics/:id` to  `CosmicsController.show`. This route catches the `/cosmics/start_batch` request before the custom route match '/cosmics/start_batch', that's why it must be put after.

You can see the routes generated by `resources :cosmics` with `rake routes` (the routes are ordered by priority). There's also an example in the [Rails routing guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#crud-verbs-and-actions).

Comment: Changing the order in the routes file worked, but why would it go to the show action? Is it the default action for any controller?

Comment: It goes there because it interprets "start_batch" as an ID for a cosmic record.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that your `match` route is below the `resources :cosmics`. Order is important here as what is happening is that it interprets `"start_match"` as the ID when it matches on the show routes on the resource `cosmics`. If you move this above `resources :comics`, you should be fine.